# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable VERY STRANGE

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

Hi just started coding and i am practicing some things but i bumped into something really strange. This is it:

```
class Hero:
def __init__(self,name,weapon):
    self.name=name
    self.health=100
    self.weapon=weapon
    if(weapon=='Sword'):
        self.damage=50
    elif(weapon=='Spear'):
        self.damage=40
    elif(weapon=='Bow'):
        self.damage=40
    elif(weapon=='Staff'):
        self.damage=60
    self.heal=20
def attack(self,a):
    a.health-=self.damage
    print(self.name,'attacked',a.name,'with a',self.weapon,'and dealt',self.damage,'damage')
    if(a.health>0):
        print(a.name,'has',a.health,'left')
    else:
        print(self.name,'killed',a.name)
def heal(self,a):
    a.health+=self.heal
    print(self.name,'healed',a.name,'with a',self.weapon,'and restored',self.heal,'health')
    print(a.name,'has',a.health,'left')
```

As you can see i just made a class to practice and after that i added two guys:

```
Bob=Hero('Bob','Spear')
Gonzo=Hero('Gonzo','Sword')
```

After that i tried the 'attack' function i created and everything went just fine:

```
>>> Bob.attack(Gonzo)
 'Bob attacked Gonzo with a Spear and dealt 40 damage
Gonzo has 60 left'
```

After that i tried the 'heal' function i created but his popped up:

```
>>> Bob.heal(Gonzo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#370>", line 1, in <module>
    Bob.heal(Gonzo)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I havent used 'heal' anywhere else so it cant be names overlaping(I checked). This is very strange because i designed the 'heal' and 'attack' functions to work exactly the same way but 'attack' works and'heal' doesnt. PLEASE HELP

Comment: Your post isn't getting positive attention because it is difficult to read.  Please have a look at the style guide and edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: "I havent used 'heal' anywhere else so it cant be names overlaping(I checked)" - Ctrl-F next time, because you did reuse the name, and Ctrl-F finds the reuse immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `__init__`, you have declared `self.heal` as an attribute... an `integer`.  Rename that variable to something besides your function name and you should be good.

Look under the `self.damage=60` line.

Comment: We only know because we have done it ourselves a hundred times.  It likely won't be the last time!  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

In your `__init__` method you define an instance variable `heal`, which is an int. This overwrites the method of the same name.

Use a different name  for that attribute; it seems like you meant `health` anyway.